# flume invalid input char

Tags: bigdata, flume

I am using Flume to ingest large amounts of data into hdfs. The input files are text files which contain ASCII character. But flume unexpectedly stops at some "unreadable" characters. I am getting the same error even after specifying the source inputCharset as ASCII or UTF-16 or UTF-32 or unicode.

Even including decodeErrorPolicy = IGNORE in the conf file doesnt have any effect. What else am I missing? any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks a lot

my config file is this

```
tier1.sources.source1.type     = spooldir
tier1.sources.source1.spoolDir = /opt/spoolDirSource
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
tier1.sources.source1.inputCharset = ASCII
tier1.sources.source1.decodeErrorPolicy = IGNORE
tier1.sources.source1.deserializer.outputCharset = ASCII
```

Answer (score 0):

Which flume version are you using? It is fixed in V1.5.0

Refer : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2052